# read_raw throws timeout error when communicating with tektronix oscilloscope using pyvisa package

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am trying to read raw data using pyvisa which communicates with MDO3014 oscilloscope.

The code I have tried is as follows:-

```
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()

usb = rm.list_resources()[0]
my_instrument = rm.open_resource(usb)
print(my_instrument.query('*IDN?'))
my_instrument.timeout = 25000

my_instrument.write('SAVE:IMAGe:FILEF PNG')
my_instrument.write('HARDCOPY:START')
raw_data = my_instrument.read_raw()
```

I am getting timeout error, the traceback of error logs is as follows:-

```
('USB0::0x0699::0x0408::C031378::INSTR', 'ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL3::INSTR')
TEKTRONIX,MDO3014,C031378,CF:91.1CT FV:v1.30

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "waveform_capture.py", line 14, in <module>
    raw_data = my_instrument.read_raw()
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\python_oscilloscope-zAKD9iXY\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 405, in read_raw
    return bytes(self._read_raw(size))
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\python_oscilloscope-zAKD9iXY\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 442, in _read_raw
    chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\python_oscilloscope-zAKD9iXY\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", 
line 2337, in read
    ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count, byref(return_count))
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\python_oscilloscope-zAKD9iXY\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", 
line 222, in _return_handler
    return self.handle_return_value(session, ret_value)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\python_oscilloscope-zAKD9iXY\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 251, 
in handle_return_value
    raise errors.VisaIOError(rv)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

Comment: Do you mean "my_instrument.write('HARDCOPY START')" without the colon? but that sends the data to a printer. Looks like you want a screen capture. Then you're better off saving the image to the file system then reading that file. If you want the data of the waveforms then there are examples in the manual that show you the list of commands to use.

Comment: The issue is with the HARDCOPY command, thank you for pointing it out @Zircatron

Comment: @Zicatron, And I am able to get the waveform image with this code. It works with Hardcopy.